# Mertens Constant and Euler–Mascheroni constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

I found this titillating equation:
$$M = \gamma + \sum_{p} \left[ \ln\! \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) + \frac{1}{p} \right]$$

where $\displaystyle M=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \left(
\sum_{p\,\leq \,n} \frac{1}{p}  - \ln(\ln n) \right)$ and $\displaystyle\gamma=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \left(
\sum_{k\,=\,1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \ln n \right)$ and $p$ ranges over the prime numbers.

Sadly I am unable to prove it. Can anyone help?

Comment: See for example Villarino's [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504289.pdf).